# Scanner in JAVA outputs gibberish instead of Hebrew

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.scanner, hebrew

I have a problem with scanning Hebrew in Netbeans.
I am trying to Scan the user's input and present in the Console, but it appears as Gibberish.

My code is:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input:");
    System.out.println("Your input is: " + input.next());
}
```

and this is the Console:

run:

Please input:

שלום

Your input is: ����

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

The same exact code works perfectly on Eclipse.
If I Println() a hebrew word it also works fine, so it's not an encoding problem.
(I am using Netbeans 7.3.1)

Thank you very much,

Barak.

Comment: Which console, the NetBeans console? It could just use a font that does not contain the Hebrew characters. For me, the Hebrew of course *is* the gibberish :)

Comment: `... so it's not an encoding problem...` -- are you sure? What is the charset encoding of the console for Eclipse and for NetBeans? Have you checked?

Comment: owlstead - yes I mean the Netbeans console.  I know it's not an encoding problem because as I said - when I just println() a hebrew word it displays it without problems.

Comment: Gibberish gets a bad rap as a language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [`Scanner(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream%29), that will use the platform default encoding to convert the *bytes* from the stream into text.

I suspect you simply need to work out what encoding your console is using, and use that either to construct an `InputStreamReader` around `System.in` to start with, or pass the encoding name as a second argument to the constructor.

Comment: Hey Joh, Thanks for the quick answer! I am trying to create an InputStreamReader, but it shows "unreported exception"       'InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8");'    Also Tried "Windows-1255". Am I doing it right?

Comment: @Bobcat100: What exception? I would expect it to give details... EDIT: Ah, yes, the `InputStreamReader` constructor can throw `UnsupportedEncodingException`. What version of Java are you using? If you're using Java 7, use `new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
 at hebrew.Hebrew.main(Hebrew.java:20)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @Bobcat100: First problem: you're trying to run code that hasn't compiled! Check for errors first - I'd expect it to give a warning before even *letting* you run...

Comment: It's getting better - now no exception, but it still does the same problem with the gibberish. Is it correct to use it in the scanner as -  InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);   Scanner input = new Scanner(in);

Comment: @Bobcat100: Yes, that's fine - but maybe UTF-8 isn't the right encoding. Do you know what your console uses?

Comment: It is Using UTF-8 (Project properties>encoding). There is another difference that might help identify the problem: when I run the program (in question) with an english word - it shows "please input", then I input for instance "Hello", and when I press Enter it shows "your input is: Hello". For hebrew words - when I press Enter it just prints an empty line, and then when I press Enter again - it shows "Your input is: םםםם".    By the way, when I change the console encoding to windows-1255, it shows: "Your input is: ????). Thanks Again!

Comment: @Bobcat100: I wouldn't have expected the *console* encoding to be part of the project properties... is it really? Sounds odd.

Comment: :Well... I guess it is, because it does change the text when I change it to something else, as mentioned before. It does show hebrew characters of the input, but not of the output (after the scanner messed it up).     Example:   run:
Please input:
שלום

Your input is: ����        I know they both seem Gibberish for you LOL.

Comment: Hmm. I'm afraid I'm lost at this point - it definitely sounds Netbeans-specific, and it's possible that their console is just a bit broken :(

Comment: it's not only in the console though... It is the same with JOptionPane.showMessageDialog, and also doesen't work when I try to scan a .txt file containing hebrew characters....     anyway thanks a lot for your time! Loved your book BTW :) @Jon

Comment: @Bobcat100: If you read a text file, then you should *definitely* know what encoding it's in. For `JOptionPane` there may be a font issue; I suggest you examine the exact code units in the string - hopefully the debugger will show you the numeric values. Then compare them with unicode.org.

Comment: Great! that fixed the problem :) I just saved the txt files with UTF-8 insteat of ansi. Now there is no problem in Netbeans or Eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Scanner in JAVA outputs gibberish instead of Hebrew.

If you want to get an input in Hebrew via the command line or powershell,
You need to check the terminal encoding on your Windows PC.

To do this just type chcp in the console

as output you should see chcp 28598

if you see diffrent number type chcp 28598

Now your console encoding is set to hebrew