# reading unicode input from user in java

Tags: java, string, input, utf-8, utf8-decode

i have simple console program in java, i try to get input from user the input is in Hebrew "שלום" but when i tried to read it i get ???? , but i wish to get "שלום" , how is the best way?

my code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args)  {

    String s;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

}

output:

run:

Enter a string

שלום

????

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

i know that i should use utf-8 but i really dont know how...
any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner in JAVA outputs gibberish instead of Hebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725603/scanner-in-java-outputs-gibberish-instead-of-hebrew)

Comment: ok.. so how do i do it? thanks

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful,  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.getBytes("UTF-8")))

Comment: Since I've marked the question as a duplicate of another question, you will find the answer to your question there. Hint: Start using a `InputReader` initialized with `new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, with this you can control the encoding of the characters until you hit the right encoding. For the console settings in an IDE like Eclipse, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385818/eclipse-character-encoding .

Comment: I use netbeans and it configured to utf-8, so I assume that it is not a configuration problem.

Comment: Scanner can be instantiated with a character set as well, say it's UTF-8 there, I believe

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows you need to check the terminal encoding.

To do this just type **chcp** in the console

as output you should see chcp **28598**

if you see diffrent number
type **chcp 28598**

Now your console encoding is set to hebrew.